# Create and manage Google Form/Typeform through my app

Tags: google-forms, typeform

I'm developing an e-learning app, and want to integrate typeform/google forms on it. What i want it's that the user could create the survey/form inside my app, or on a popup, without the need to login on typeform/google forms. O saw that typeform have one "create api", but, using that, i would need to create a form builder, right?

There's other alternatives that could help me with this?

thanks!